# Cardiopulmonary capacity assessment

Tags: cardiology, lungs, internal-organs, blood-vessels, autopsy

Is it possible to determine someone's cardiopulmonary capacity from organ/tissue/blood samples alone?

No other clues allowed. Think about a non cooperative patient, who can lie in an anamnesis, or fake exhaustion in a treadmill tests and so on.

Also no patient record investigation allowed.

Only tissues and blood sample. Maybe organs inspection (either live or dead).

What features physically (in tissues and organs) embodies the concept of a good or bad cardiopulmonary capacity?

Perhaps the blood vessels network or something like that?

Comment: Are you trying to detect heart failure or something else? (Like someone faking an army test in a country with compulsory service?)

Comment: Hehehehe nice. But no. I'm only trying to understand which changes did my body undergo back then when I started a more serious training, and changes after I became sedentary again.

Comment: Usually the google answer to my question is: "your heart learns to be more efficient". I just want to know if there are physical markers to this "learning". That's why I suggested the blood vessels network. But maybe there are more... Perhaps thicker heart muscle, or bigger lungs (is it even possible?).

Comment: Perhaps some chemical change? A better type of hemoglobin? Maybe more hemoglobin per red cell? Better red cell geometry?

Comment: If such tests existed, I think they'd be in high demand by professional and amateur sports organizations, and if easy and affordable, by the public in general. A simple, cheap test of that sort would be worth billions, so it's not like pharma companies wouldn't pursue it. So either they don't exist at all, or they're not feasible for some reason. My guess is that reason is a lack of scientific validity.

Comment: @CareyGregory all your considerations are valid. But I'd like to add another: maybe such "test" would cost the life of the patient. See, I was not really thinking of something quick and easy to rate the fitness/capacity of an athlete (like a blood test or CT scan). Perhaps such a method to determine if someone was fit could be done in an autopsy.

Comment: I think it will be apparent to a coroner whether the person was physically fit based on things such as muscle mass, body fat, condition of the lungs, heart, etc. But a quantitative measurement of cardiopulmonary capacity? I very much doubt that. Why would anyone invest the time and effort developing and validating such a test?

Comment: Please, don't focus on a fixed procedure, it was not my intention when I posed the question. The important thing is what would a physician or coroner see (to the naked eye, or under a microscope, or something else) in the tissues and organs of a fit persons vs. non-fit one. But I'm ok with "there is nothing to be seen". Just like thoughts and memories are impressed in our brains and nobody can see them from outside, maybe the idea that "your heart becomes more efficient in pumping blood" is also deeply engraved somewhere.

Comment: Perhaps given 2 individuals, one fit and the other non-fit, and otherwise identical individuals, maybe there is no difference tissuewise or organwise.

Comment: Okay, that's actually a good question, but you need to edit and make your question ask that, not what it's currently asking. You want to know how a coroner would judge the physical fitness of a cadaver with no history available.

Comment: And while you're editing, could you please correct the spelling of "cardiopulmonar?" Perhaps your first language is Spanish or Portuguese? In English the word is spelled "cardiopulmonary."

Comment: Corrected the spelling (you're right, portuguese is my native language). I'm still pondering on the exact words for the other suggestion.

Comment: @CareyGregory: well, there's EPO-levels testing in blood... at least for anti-doping purposes, but I'm not too sure how well it correlates with fitness in the average person... A quick search didn't find any clear studies, perhaps because there's a ton of them on supplementing EPO... There's https://journals.physiology.org/doi/full/10.1152/ajpregu.00012.2017 on natural changes with training but results across studies seem inconsistent.

Comment: Total hemoglobin correlates pretty well wtih VO2 max ... again in performance athletes https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6225968/

Comment: @Fizz I bet both those measures also correlate well with people who live at high altitudes who aren't athletes.